# How to change html content with URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I'm a beginner at coding, I know javascript but not super advanced objectd,
I'd like to know how to change html content with its URL. For example,I am on a website like GMAIL, it has different page of registring and logging in. These two pages have different URLs.

What I'd like to know is how do they change the URL along with HTML when I click on the button "Log in". Is this possible through server-side like node.js and express, or just with front-end javascript?

One last thing, do websites have multiple web pages or it's just in one single HTML file?

Well, I have set up a practice project, but I don't know what I am doing. 
I changed HTML content with jQuery library but I don't know how to change URL.

First I made a homepage with some text and two links to two forms.

I showed registration form when click on "Sign in", and log in form on "Log in", and hid the homepage with the show() and hide(). The URL doesn't change in order to work with it with express. I tried it with history.pushState() but it messed up things: I can't return to homepage, and it didn't change the URL i wanted based on the form. So i deleted it, and I am stuck and don't know I could find some tutorials online.

My code doesn't contain anything other than what I described.

So, please can you explain to me how websites do that.

And one other thing, my express server now is very slow, it takes nearly 5min to start. I don't know if it's because my pc which is old and not super good unfortunately.

Can you please advice me with some tutorials and tips?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You are asking basic but big questions of web development and we can't simply answer all of them. You will have to do your own research on basics of web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that your question is too broad. Even there is many years invested in unversity to know these stuff well, I believe in self learning, so I will give you some light for your next steps in this world.

Here are some questions you may ask Google or research where ever you want:

There's both applications that hosts entire html documents in a server and reacts to http requirements responding with different ones. These are the first ones in existence.

Today the trend is to host information on distributed servers (Even cloud) as services to interact with just as information repositories, and entire client side applications that handles that information to show to the user in a more interaction friendly way.

So here are 4 first questions you can ask:

1. How does HTTP protocol works (with html documents e.g.)?
2. What's the difference between thin client and fat client applications?
3. What are web services?
4. How can I do a simple client side application with different routes using a public web service?

There is a lot of information to read about, and that's not the way I learned in university, so I can not tell you that's the right way or even a good one. Anyway, you should consider taking a web programmer beginner course, if you already know about basic algorithmic composition.

Wish you the best in this extensive path...

Comment: Thank you for your advices.